# ProgressDialog not shown when AsyncTask.get() called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AsyncTask block UI threat and show progressbar with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583137/asynctask-block-ui-threat-and-show-progressbar-with-delay)

I want to show a progressDialog while retrieving JSON from any server. So I had used AsyncTask  as a solution (not sure any different way out).

Everything is fine, the ProgressDialog works properly until I call .get() method using AsyncTask instance. I suppose it's blocking UI somehow. Here is my AsyncTask:

```java
public class myAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, List> {

    String message; // for dialog message
    ProgressDialog progress; 
    Intent myIntent;
    Context ctx;

    public myAsync(String message, Context ctx) {
        this.message = message;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        progress = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        progress.setMessage(message);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();    
    }

    @Override
    protected List doInBackground(String... params) {
        //returns any list after the task
        return anyList; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
        if(progress.isShowing())
            progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And here is myActivity which is calls AsyncTask:

```java
myAsync asyncTask = new myAsync("Loading...", this);
asyncTask.execute("Any string", "Other string");
asyncTask.get(); // If I comment out this line, ProgressDialog works
```

After execute, when I tried to log the result from doInBackground and onPostExecute both there is no problem. But if I want to get with .get() the result ProgressDialog is not shown or shown so little time (maybe 0.2 seconds)

What's the problem?

Comment: are you hiting any exception?

Comment: Not really. As I said, the dialog window can be seen so so little time. Indeed it should be seen 2 seconds at least.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, `get()` **waits** if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result. This means, that you are blocking your UI thread, waiting for the result.

Solution: Don't call `get`

Usually, you will call a function (callback) in the `postExecute`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291490/common-class-for-asynctask-in-android for a sample implementation

Comment: Got it! Thanks for sample, solved this but still have problems for different subject.

Comment: but if i want to use return value of AsyncTask and on the base of return value i wannt to call new URL so what can i do for this??
i think in this way we must have to use .get without it if there is any option then pls help me

Comment: Another way : if your code executed on UI thread, wrap your AsyncTask by new thread...  ex) new Thread(new Runnable(){.... result = yourAsyncTask.execute().get();.....}).start();

Comment: Helped me after wasting 2 hours. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 16):

Calling [`.get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) changes your `AsyncTask` into an effective "`SyncTask`" as it causes the current thread (which would be the UI thread) to wait until the `AsyncTask` has finished its processing. Since you are now blocking the UI thread the call to the `ProgressDialog`'s `.show()` method never gets a chance to allow the dialog to draw itself the screen.

Removing the call will allow it to run properly in the background.

If you need to do processing after the task has completed I suggest you either put it inside the `onPostExecute` method itself or use a callback to the `Activity` from `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I guess you're right but can you explain it more? Any snippets. Because I'm not sure about how to use callback from onPostExecute. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to update the progress of your AsyncTask in a `ProgressDialog` and this isn't currently working. So a couple of things to note: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `.get()` but I'll assume you want to display the progress.

I've modified your program below to update the UI thread with your AsyncTask's progress. Everytime you need to *update* the progress, update that `prog` variable in the `doInBackground` method.

```
public class myAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List> {

  String message; // for dialog message
  ProgressDialog progress; 
  Intent myIntent;
  Context ctx;

  public myAsync(String message, Context ctx) {
    this.message = message;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    progress = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() { 
    // Runs on the UI thread
    progress.setMessage(message);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();    
  }

  @Override
  protected List doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Runs in the background thread
    // publish your progress here!!
    int prog = 5; // This number will represent your "progress"
    publishProgress(prog);
    return anyList; 
  }


  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // Runs in the UI thread
    // This method will fire (on the UI thread) EVERYTIME publishProgress
    // is called.
    Log.d(TAG, "Progress is: " +progress);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
    // Runs in the UI thread

    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
      Log.d(TAG, "List item: " + result.get(i));
    }

    if(progress.isShowing())
      progress.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: With `get`, he obviously wants to get the result from the task, in order to update his interface

Comment: @rds Would _you_ ever use `.get` in the context of an AsyncTask? Hence why my _assumption_ "I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with..." and then on to my interpretation of the OP's question.

Comment: @Marvin, firstly thanks for your comment. Simply, I'm getting json from a web server. While doing this transaction, just want to show progressdialog windows, that's all. If I do not call .get(), it's fine. Dialog is shown as soon as clicked the button (button'll trigger async). But by the way I need json result too. As I know .get() method returns the result. When I tried to get, dialog window is shown so little time during the transaction. I hope it's easier now.

Comment: @OgulcanOrhan Try out the suggestions the other answerers posted and if you're still stuck, I can try to help you out.

Comment: @OgulcanOrhan I've made a minor edit to my answer's `onPostExecute` method to demonstrate how you would _process_ the items in your list on the _UI Thread_. So if you have to for example update a ListView, you would do that in the `onPostExecute` method. This would be what I presume you're trying to do. i.e. After it's done executing, get and _do something_ with your results. Well the _do something_ part is what you want to put in the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: @MarvinPinto Your code is not suitable with me. After the task, I need to pass the result Activity too. So I solved it by using another callback method. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try using runOnUiThread like this:

```
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                dialog.show();
                }});
```

Running something on a AsyncTask means that its running away from the UIthread so usually you cant run ui operations from inside Async methods without handlers and stuff which I usually stay away from. I also handle such a solution by creating a progressDialog as a variable in my class above my oncreate so its visible to the whole class. I then call the progressdialog right before my asynctask and then since its visible to the whole class I call .dissmiss() in the onPostExecute

Comment: Both `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` are run on the UI thread. `doInBackground` is the only thing that is not.

Comment: @JakeWharton I think they only return data to the UI thread and do not run on it but I could be wrong.....I dont exactly have the android documentation remembered line for line yet lol

Comment: I already tried this, not worked. Thanks anyway.