# AsynTask - onPostExecute is called before doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-tasks-api

i got a problem getting my `AsyncTask` to work correct. My App offers the possibility to connect with your Google Account and add and receive tasks by using the Tasks API. When the users wants to synchronize with his account, the `doInBackground()` method is started. Right before that, a `ProgressDialog` is displayed in the `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask` class.
If the synchronisation has been successfully executed, the `onPostExecute()` method 'should' be called fading out the `ProgressDialog`.
But there is problem: the `onPostExecute()` ethod is called before the work in the `doInBackground()` is finished. 
In `doInBackground()` I receive the token used for the authorization:

```
token = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

That's all. But right before that, the `onPostExecute()` is called and the `ProgressDialog` disappears while the token is still retrieving.  The wired thing is that when I start the app and synchronizes for the first time, it works like it should. But after that the `onPostExecute()` method finishes before the work is completed. Does this have to do that there are requests to a server while executing

```
future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

How can I tell the `onPostExecute()` method that there is still work to do?

```
private class SynchronizeGoogle extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> 
    {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(RememberMe.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Listen werden geladen...");
        this.dialog.show();
     }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
        try 
            {
            switch(startSynchronize())
                {
                    case 0: 
                        publishProgress(0);
                        return null;
                    case 1: 
                        publishProgress(1);
                        return null;
                    case 2: 
                        publishProgress(2);
                        return null;
                }
            } 
        catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                    synchronize();


        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... type)
    {
        int typeCase = type[0];
        switch(typeCase)
        {
            case 0:
                showDialog(DIALOG_INTERNET_ACCESS);
                break;
            case 1:
                showDialog(DIALOG_CREATE_ACCOUNT);
                break;
            case 2:
                showDialog(DIALOG_ACCOUNTS);
                break;

        }


    }

      protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) 
      {


          if (this.dialog.isShowing()) 
          {
             this.dialog.dismiss();
          }

      }
}
```

And here my startSynchronize() and synchronize() methods:

```
private int startSynchronize() throws IOException
{
            googleAccountManager = new GoogleAccountManager(RememberMe.this);
    Account[] accounts = googleAccountManager.getAccounts();

    if(checkAccess.internetAccess() == false)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(accounts.length == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    else
        {
            if(accounts.length == 1)
            {
                account = accounts[0];

            }
            else
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }

    return -1;
}   

private void synchronize()
{       
myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

String oldToken = myPrefs.getString(MY_TOKEN, "");

    if(oldToken.length() > 0)
        {
                            // invalidate old token to be able to receive a new one
            googleAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken(oldToken); 

        }

    googleAccountManager.manager.getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() 
            {
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) 
                    {
                        try 
                            {

                        token = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                                         prefsEditor.putString(MY_TOKEN, token);
                                prefsEditor.commit();

                    useTasksAPI(token);

                            } 
                    catch (OperationCanceledException e) 
                            {
                            //...
                            } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                            //...
                            }
                    }
          }, null);


}
```

In the Optionsmenu i start it like this

```
new SynchronizeGoogle().execute();
```

Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: Please post more information, your AsyncTask implementation or where you are executing it would be resourceful.

Comment: If I had to guess, `doInBackground()` is kicking off asynchronous work and returning.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i added the missing code

Answer (score 3):

If I do not misunderstand your question, you're wrong with `getResult()` method usage.

When `getResult()` called by anywhere in your code, AsyncTask does not wait until finish. So you need to do your process in `onPostExecute` method.

I recommend you this [question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019249/progressdialog-not-shown-when-asynctask-get-called). I hope, it's gonna help you.