# How can I pass an object to my AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an object `Car` that has this constructor:

```
public Car(int idCar, String name)
{
    this.idCar = idCar;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Here I don't have any problem so I created one object `Car` named `newCar`, like this:

```
Car newCar = new Car(1,"StrongCar");
```

The problem that I have it's that I want to pass this `newCar` to my `AsyncTask`, named `modifyCar` as a parameter, but I don't know how to do this.

I have searched in SO and I found this question: [AsyncTask passing custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191479/asynctask-passing-custom-objects)
but it doesn't solved my problem because in the solution that it is given they only pass an `String` to the `AsyncTask` and not the entirely object.

**What I want it's to pass the entirely object as a parameter to the AsyncTask.**

According to the solution that it is given in the question that I put above, I tried to do this to pass the object to the `AsyncTask`.

```
new modifyCar(newCar).execute();
```

So I declared the AsyncTask like this:

```
class modifyCar extends AsyncTask<Car, Integer, ArrayList<Evento>> {
 protected void onPreExecute()
 {
 }

 protected ArrayList<Evento> doInBackground(Car... newCarAsync) 
 {
     //The rest of the code using newCarAsync
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate()
 {
 }

 protected void onPostExecute()
 {
 }
}
```

But I don't know if it is correct or not. If not, what I should do for that purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution that you read is right, you just did it wrong. You needed to create a constructor for your AsyncTask class easily and pass the object to it

```
class modifyCar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Evento>> {
    private Car newCar;

    // a constructor so that you can pass the object and use
    modifyCar(Car newCar){
        this.newCar = newCar;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
    }

    protected ArrayList<Evento> doInBackground(Void... parms) 
    {
        //The rest of the code using newCarAsync
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate()
    {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute()
    {
    }
}
```

and to execute this class

```
// pass the object that you created
new modifyCar(newCar).execute();
```

Comment: But, in the `doInBackground()` method, how can I use the object `Car` in it? Or `newCarAsync` it's the same as the object `newCar` that it's declared in the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @Error404 The object that you created is now passed to the class, inside the class or `doInBackground()` it's `newCar`

Comment: Then, what it's the purpose of `newCarAsync` variable in the `doInBackground()` method?

Comment: @Error404 It's useless, I just didn't want to change your class, I edited the class above

Comment: Thank you very much! You help me a lot! ;)

Answer (score 4):

It makes no difference if your object is an instance of `String` or a `Car` or a `AbstractDeathRayController`, the expected way to pass them to an `AsyncTask` is through the [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) method:

```
new modifyCar().execute(car);
```

BTW, Java [convention for class names](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) is to use *CamelCase*, so it might be a good idea to rename your class to `ModifyCar`.

Comment: Might be good to show how to access it in `doInBackground()` as well, as some have a hard time understanding varargs.

Comment: As @DanielNugent said, I need to know how to access it in `doInBackground()` method because I don't really understand what you exactly want to say.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the Car object on the execute method. You can read it in the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params,
>   Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground,
>   onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute

Follow the documentation example:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

And call the async task with:

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```