# off AsyncTask if loading more than a certain time(android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Sorry for my English. I want to do if the loading AsyncTask is continued over a certain time (in my case, more than 1 second) everything is canceled and a message is displayed to the user "Please check the Internet", I have a message displayed, but ProgressDialog continues to run.

```
    SendRequestAutorization sendAvtoriz = new SendRequestAutorization ();

    //code

         try {
                                sendAvtoriz.execute(
                                        new String[]{login.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()}).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Avtorization", e.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check the Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                sendAvtoriz.cancel(true);
                            }


//code
private class SendRequestAutorization extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Avtorization.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Authorization");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//code
   return null;
        }

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

I'm doing all right? I need another off ProgressDialog, it is right?

**UDP:**

Ideally, that's what I want to do: in app click button "avtorization" is showed animation loading(AsyncTask work) if loading more 5 second i display message "Please check the Internet" else i enter my profile. Now i have: in click button "avtorization" if i have internet 5 second nothing showed, showed fast loading animation and enter profile, if i have not internet and click "avtorization" nothing showed 5 secont then display "Please check the Internet"

Its my code now:

```
private Button logInn;
 private SendRequestAutorization sendAvtoriz;
 ProgressDialog pDialog;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p_avtorization);

 logInn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createAccount);
 sendAvtoriz = new SendRequestAutorization();


 logInn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Avtorization.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Authorization");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();


try {
                        sendAvtoriz.execute(
                                new String[]{login.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()}).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Avtorization", e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check the Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        sendAvtoriz.cancel(true);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
}

}

 //code
    private class SendRequestAutorization extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //code
       return null;
            }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
```

Comment: Did you try HTTP timeout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get result from AsyncTask with timeout, look at method [get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

This method blocks UI thread, so for this case better not to call get() method, but to create TimerTask, which will cancel AsyncTask after 5 seconds if it is still working.

also look:
[ProgressDialog not shown when AsyncTask.get() called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019249/progressdialog-not-shown-when-asynctask-get-called)

Comment: i use this, in my code its somthing like this `sendAvtoriz.execute(
                                        new String[]{login.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()}).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` but if i set `get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` 5 second i cant see ProgressDialog animation then its showed

Comment: I cant understand, do you mean that after 5 seconds animation of ProgressDialog freezes?

Comment: Ideally, that's what I want to do: in app click button "avtorization" is showed animation loading(AsyncTask work) if loading more 5 second i display message  "Please check the Internet" else i enter my profile. Now i have: in click button "avtorization" if i have internet 5 second nothing showed, showed fast loading animation and enter profile, if i have not internet and click "avtorization" nothing showed 5 secont then display "Please check the Internet"

Comment: First, if TimeOutException thrown in doInBackground() method, pDialog.dismiss() will not be called, so create pDialog outside of AsyncTask to access it in catch statement

Comment: please look my code, i update my qestion. I edit what you say but its not work