# Return value from AsyncTask class onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, return-value

Ok so now I have `Class A` that contains some spinners that values will be populated by `Class B` that extends `AsnycTask` which grabs the spinner values from a web service. In class B i manage to retrieve the values, showing in a Toast. The problem now is how do I pass those spinner values back to Class A?

I've tried

[Can OnPostExcecute method in AsyncTask RETURN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005353/can-onpostexcecute-method-in-asynctask-return-values)

by passing `Class A` to `Class B` and store the value in a public variable of `Class A` like below

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
  classA.classAvariable = result;
}
```

However whenever I try to read the `classAvariable` i always get a `NullPointer Exception`.
Seems like the variable was never assigned with the result.
For readability purpose I needed to seperate `Class B` instead of using as an inline class.

Any ideas my fellow Java programmers?

Comment: Provide the code that you have written

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that when you execute your AsynchTask, its doInBackground() methode run in separate thread and the thread that have started this AsynchTask move forward, Thereby changes occur on your variable by AsynchTask does not reflect on parent thread (who stated this AsynchTask) immediately.

Example --

```
class MyAsynchTask
{

doInbackground()
{
a = 2;
}

}


int a = 5;

new MyAsynchTask().execute();
```

// here a still be 5

Comment: well if you did read my code i did the assignment in the onPostExecute method.. which is supposedly to be running on the UI thread no?

Comment: yes! onPostExecute runs in UI thread but after the completion of doInbackground.

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface  like `OnCompletRequest()` then pass this to your ClassB constructor and simply call the method inside this interface such as `complete(yourList list)`  in the method of `onPostExecute(String result)`

Comment: Do you mind providing a short code snippet? Im unclear of how do I implement the interface in the AsyncTask class.

Comment: i have just update the code of @Nunu to help you that how it will work.

Comment: Thanks you very much! It was much helpful!

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the return value of `protected Boolean doInBackground()` by calling the `get()` method of `AsyncTask` class :

E.g. you have `AsyncTask` class as `dbClass` like

```
dbClass bg = new dbClass(this);
String Order_id = bg.execute(constr,data).get();
```

Here I am passing `constr` as URL and `data` as string of inputs to make my class dynamic.

But be careful of the responsiveness of the UI, because `get()` waits for the computation to complete and will block the UI thread.