# How to store value from onPostExecute method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment in side a activity. I want to make a class that extend AsyncTask separately. How i can execute the AsyncTask from fragment and get value of Asyntask class in fragment.
for example suppose it is my fragment class

```
public class FeePayFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fee_pay, container, false);}
}
```

and here is Asyntask

```
public class AsyFeeDues extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        JSONArray rootJsonArray;
        JSONObject rootJsonObject;
        private String compCode,session,admNo;
        boolean checkSeverResponse;
        public AsyFeeDues(String compCode, String session, String admNo) {
            this.compCode = compCode;
            this.session = session;
            this.admNo = admNo;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            RestApi api = new RestApi();
            try {
                rootJsonObject = api.GetFeeDues(compCode, session, admNo);
                checkSeverResponse  = (rootJsonObject != null);
                if(checkSeverResponse) {
                    boolean isSuccess = rootJsonObject.optBoolean(TAG_SUCESSFULL);
                    rootJsonArray = rootJsonObject.optJSONArray(TAG_VALUE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < rootJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = rootJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                        int amount = jsonObject.optInt(TAG_AMOUNT);
                        if (amount > 0) {
                            int period = jsonObject.optInt(TAG_PERIOD);
                            if (period <= periodMonth) {
                                String feeCode = jsonObject.optString(TAG_FEECODE);
                                String feeHead = jsonObject.optString(TAG_FEEHEAD);
                                String periodName = jsonObject.optString(TAG_PERIODNAME);

                                boolean checkFeeKey = feeDuesDetails.containsKey(feeHead);
                                if (checkFeeKey) {
                                    totalBalanceAmount = totalBalanceAmount + amount;
                                    Map p = feeDuesDetails.get(feeHead);
                                    int previousAmount = (Integer) p.get(TAG_AMOUNT);
                                    int upDateAmount = previousAmount + amount;
                                    feeDuesDetails.get(feeHead).put(TAG_AMOUNT, upDateAmount);
                                } else {
                                    totalBalanceAmount = totalBalanceAmount + amount;
                                    map = new HashMap();
                                    map.put(TAG_AMOUNT, amount);
                                    feeDuesDetails.put(feeHead, map);
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if(checkSeverResponse) {
                if (feeDuesDetails.size() > 1) {
                    Set keys = feeDuesDetails.keySet();
                    for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                        String key = (String) i.next();
                        feeHead.add(key);
                        Map map = feeDuesDetails.get(key);
                        int feeHeadWiseAmount = (Integer) map.get(TAG_AMOUNT);
                        feeAmount.add(feeHeadWiseAmount);
                    }
                    feeDuesAdapter = new FeeDuesAdapter(getActivity(), feeHead, feeAmount);
                    feeDuesList.setAdapter(feeDuesAdapter);
                   totalAmountInRs.setText(String.valueOf(totalBalanceAmount));
                    paybleAmount.setText("Total Payable Amount");


                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your fee paid up to this month", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server not response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

I want all value in my fragment that is retrieve in `doInBackground` method variable like feecode,feehead,period etc

Comment: please add interface and call it form u r onPostExecute method and get a call back in u r fragmet

Comment: This answer may help you
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815807/return-value-from-asynctask-class-onpostexecute-method)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815807/return-value-from-asynctask-class-onpostexecute-method[This type of issue has been resloved on stackoverflow][1]

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean? To get objects from your Asynctask you must return a value in do `inbackground()`. In order to do that you have to parse your JSON in objects(models) so you can return a fee-object. Once you have this, you will have to update your ui when the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has three parameters defined for it:

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
>      background computation.
> 3. Result, the type of the result of the
>      background computation.

Go through the google docs for clarification:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can achieve that by doing the following:

An interface to handle such things:

```
public interface MyListener{
     public void onTaskComplete(int status, String data);
}
```

Then your asynctask

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    MyListener mMyListener;
    public MyAsyncTask(MyListener myListener){
         mMyListener = myListener;
    }
    ...
    public String doInBackground(Void... params){
         String valueToReturn;
         //Your code here to get the required data to set the "valueToRetun"
         return valueToReturn;
    }
    ...
    public void onPostExecute(String data){ <- you get that data here
         //Your code here
         mMyListener.onTaskComplete(1, data); <- 1  being the success status
    }
}
```

Let your activity implement the listener:

```
public class MyActivity implements MyLisntener{
     ...Your code here
     public void startTask(){
          MyAsyncTask mt = new MyAsyncTask(this);
          mt.execute();
     }

     @Override
     public void onTaskComplete(String data){
          //Process your data here
     }

     ...Your code here
}
```

I'm assuming you need to return String. Replace it with your modal object in case you are expecting the asynctask to return something else.

Hope it helps :)