# Returning a string onPostExecute() in Async class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I made a login application, that sends login data to my server, and the server then returns what type of user it is(admin, etc...)

I do that with the OkHttp library, and for the http request I made a second class extending Async. Now I want to know I'm my main class(activity) what my website responded. How can I give the message: "hey I finished loading, here's the variable" to my main page, so I can wait there for the message and then react according to its outcome?

Comment: async task you calling are in same activity right?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem a few months back now. Found this back then and it worked for me. Hope it helps!

[Return value from AsyncTask class onPostExecute method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815807/return-value-from-asynctask-class-onpostexecute-method)

Comment: while this may be useful, it does not answer the question and should not be listed as an answer. please post things like this as comments