# How to return value from async task in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I created an async task to call my server to get data from DB.
I need to process the result returned from http server call.
From my activity i calling the async task in many places. so i cant use member variable to access the result. is there any way to do?

```
public Result CallServer(String params)
{

    try
    {
    new MainAynscTask().execute(params);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aResultM;//Need to get back the result

}  

    private class MainAynscTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Result> {


    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(String... ParamsP) {    
        //calling server codes
        return aResultL;
    }       
    @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          //how i will pass this result where i called this task?
       }
```

Comment: Why not call a method that handles the value as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458274/1021640?

Comment: possibly duplicate of [Async](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458258/return-value-from-async-task-in-android) and 
[Async And](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457493/asynctask-return-value)

Comment: The right way is using [protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820666/2835520)

Answer (score 15):

Try to call the get() method of AsyncTask after you call the execute() method. This works for me

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()

```
public Result CallServer(String params)
{
   try
   {
       MainAynscTask task = new MainAynscTask();
       task.execute(params);
       Result aResultM = task.get();  //Add this
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   return aResultM;//Need to get back the result

} 
...
...
```

Comment: AsyncTask it's executed in other thread, if you try to do that, your main thread will be frizzed while the task don´t end getting the data from  server, and the activity cannot handle user events when touch the screen.

Comment: I would not recommend using get as above, because assignment is synchronous.

Comment: this  will work but surely not a way to adopt. tis is good for  educational projects but not in real time apps
Reason : it makes the app laggy but holding on to the main thread which defies the whole purpose of using Async task

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways i can suggest -

1. `onPostExecute(Result)` in `AsyncTask`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)
2. Send a broadcast with the result as an extra.

`AsyncTask` is an asynchronous task so it does NOT make sense to return the result to the caller. Rather handle the result in `onPostExecute()` like setting the value to `TextView` etc. Or send a broadcast so that some other listener can handle the result.

Comment: O̶n̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶t̶t̶l̶e̶ ̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶:̶ ̶I̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶`V̶i̶e̶w̶`s ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶`o̶n̶P̶o̶s̶t̶E̶x̶e̶c̶u̶t̶e̶(̶)̶` ̶(̶e̶.̶g̶.̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶a̶n̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶e̶a̶d̶)̶,̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶ `A̶c̶t̶i̶v̶i̶t̶y̶.̶r̶u̶n̶O̶n̶U̶i̶T̶h̶r̶e̶a̶d̶(̶.̶.̶.̶)̶`;̶  - forget it, `onPostExecute()` is invoked on UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got around this:

1) Create an interface class that defines a signature for a method to execute on completion:

```
public interface AsyncIfc {
    public void onComplete();
}
```

2) Set a property on your AsyncTask class to hold the delegate method:

```
    public AsyncIfc completionCode;
```

3) Trigger the delegate from onPostExecute() in the AsyncTask:

```
completionCode.onComplete();
```

4) From your calling logic, set the delegate property to an anonymous method:

```
task.completionCode = new AsyncIfc() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
    // Any logic you want to happen after execution
    }
};
```